# Calling a function in an imported package - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have this project structure

```
Bot/
-- bot.py
FlapPyBird/
-- flappy.py
run.py
```

bot.py:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def run(upperPipes, lowerPipes, playerInfo):
    pass
```

flappy.py:

```
from itertools import cycle
import random
import sys

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def doStuff(bot)
    some stuff
```

and run.py:

```
import FlapPyBird as game
import Bot as bot

def main():
    game.doStuff(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And I'm getting this error running 'python run.py'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Kyle/IdeaProjects/flappy_bird_bot/run.py", line 8, in <module>
main()
File "C:/Users/Kyle/IdeaProjects/flappy_bird_bot/run.py", line 5, in main
game.doStuff(Bot)

AttributeError: module 'FlapPyBird' has no attribute 'doStuff'
```

What am I not understanding? How can I abstract away my two packages so I can call them from my root directory?

Comment: `doStuff` is in `FlapPyBird.flappy`, not the `FlapPyBird` package itself.

Comment: you are a lifesaver!

Comment: @user2357112 That looks like it should have been an answer